# Android Studio: debugging junit test: wrong values are assigned

Tags: android, junit

Good day my fellow developers,

I've written my first unit test in Android Studio. However the behavior is weird or I'm doing something wrong.

In this test I simply create an android.graphics.PointF with X=3 and y=0. But as it turns out from logger, it is always 0. Here is a screenshot. I'm currently on next line from the logging and as you can see in Concole:
INFO: u2: x=0.0 y=0.0

[Oh, I'm not allowed to embed images on SO, so please click here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLpzM.png)

Anything I'm doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it by setting x, and y after contructor ...

```
PointF f = new PointF(12f, 15f);
        f.y = 12f;
        f.x = 15f;
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know but I had the same problem with Rect and RectF classes which are also in Android graphics

Comment: If there is nothing I'm missing, it is a bug. Should we file it in android bug tracker?

Answer (score 1):

OK, this behavior is because:

> By default, the Android Plug-in for Gradle executes your local unit tests against a modified version of the android.jar library, which does not contain any actual code. Instead, method calls to Android classes from your unit test throw an exception.

from here: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html#mocking-dependencies

This explains everything. So what we need to do is to mock the whole bunch of the methods of PointF.
BTW, setting public fields .x and .y does work simply because there are no setters behind them, so no exception is thrown.

Actually this all is just weird.